# Does an adverb of frequency always have to be between the noun and verb?

Tags: adverbs

For example take this sentence:

> If it's summer, then I sometimes like going to the beach.

But would this also be correct:

> If it's summer, then sometimes I like going to the beach.

Comment: I like going to the beach sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should an adverb go before or after a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/should-an-adverb-go-before-or-after-a-verb)

Answer (score 2):

*Sometimes* is a odd adverb of frequency because it does not follow the standard placement rules which many of the others do (always, regularly, never etc). It can be placed at the beginning, end or in either of the positions you have highlighted in your example. The placement can add emphasis to your sentence.

Visit here for more info - https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/position-frequency-adverbs/

Comment: Hello, Westi. That looks like a good article, and I don't think this is a duplicate. Why not show it?